# Twitter4j reply to tweet not working

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to reply to a tweet (that i post 10 seconds before) using twitter4j but it is only posting it to the timeline and not as a reply.

```
post = mainTwitter.updateStatus(...); //1st twitter account
StatusUpdate reply = new StatusUpdate(...);
try {
   reply.setInReplyToStatusId(post.getId());
   contextTwitter.updateStatus(reply); //2nd twitter account
} catch (TwitterException e) {
   System.err.println("Couldn't post context");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The id is not -1, it is the right long value. No exception thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to make your snippet working

```
public void init() {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
      .setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET);
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    twitter = tf.getInstance();
}


/***
 * 
 * @param tweetId : tweet Id
 * @param messgae : Reply message
 * @return
 * @throws TwitterException
 */
public String reply(String tweetId, String messgae ) throws TwitterException {
        Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong(tweetId));
        Status reply = twitter.updateStatus(new StatusUpdate(" @" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " "+ messgae).inReplyToStatusId(status.getId()));
    return Long.toString(reply.getId());
}
```

Usage :

```
reply("930497966443454464", " Hello Eva")
```